# F# on Unity/Mono 2.6

Tags: f#, mono, unity-game-engine

So I have been working on an editor extension for the Unity 3D game engine. It's written in F# due to the nature of it (graph editor, F# lends itself very well for this type of programming).

Now my question is: How is the F# support on Unity/Mono 2.6? So far it seems to be working fine, and I have not had any issues. But it would be nice to hear from others that have used F# on Mono 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

As you [found out for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966733), Unity does not come bundled with F#'s dlls, so it is non-ideal for making an extension that will be redistributed with games, since the game-authors would have to redistribute the F#-dlls for their games as well.

However, if it is purely an editor extension, I don't know of any issues.